# Need to specify external ip in proxy_pass instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 -How to fix this?

Tags: nginx, debian, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute Engine instance running with Debian 10 and nginx. Using proxy_pass to pass calls from the frontend to the backend I have

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123:8080;
}
```

This works. But I am currently not using a fixed IP and thus don't want to hardcode the external IP (123.123.123.123) here. If I replace the external IP in this proxy_pass declaration with localhost or 127.0.0.1, it does not work: The browser receives 502 Bad Gateway when calling /api/.

I can ping localhost and 127.0.0.1 from the console.

Interestingly, I have the same problem with mysql. I need to supply my backend application with the servers external IP address for it to be able to access mysql.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No way to say without seeing more of your configuration. How is your backend server configured (VirtualHosts/server block/equivalent of it), on what interfaces are your services bound? Log files might have some helpful information as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this concrete case (GCP - Google Compute Engine VM) the solution was to use the (by default fixed/permanent) internal IP, instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 or the external IP.